# AD: Roll out an MSI application at midnight

Tags: windows-server-2003, msi, scheduling

Using Windows Server's Active Directory and Group Policy, is there a way to roll out an MSI file at a scheduled time, like midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strickly speaking no.  GPOs are not scheduled tasks.  They run when the system updates (reboots, etc).

We use Quest's GPOAdmin.  It allows for time-based deployment of GPOs.  This could help somewhat.

Sounds like you really need a software deployment systems (SCCM, LANDesk, etc)

Comment: Sounds like he needs a scheduled task, set to run at midnight, to reboot the machines that are running and wake machines that are asleep. I do this kind of thing fairy frequently. It's very handy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It took me a while to create a mirror account here. As a product developer the problem is using a baseline that all clients will have, and it is a disappointment to see that GPO and Active Directory only provide "immediate" deployments, but no forced "run x script daily at 4pm regardless of whether someone's logged off"